# Python recursion error when multiplying functions

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm using python 3 and trying to multiply functions within a for loop. I wrote a simple example code to demonstrate my problem. What I want this code to do was to start with the funciton x^2, then multiply it by x^2 in first loop, to get x^4. Then multiply x^4 again with x^2 to get x^6 e.t.c.

```
fun = lambda x: x**2

function = lambda x: x**2
for i in range(2):
    function = lambda x: function(x) * fun(x)

print(function(2))
```

But the code comes out with a Recursion error. I have no idea how this is causing a recursion though? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment in your loop is equivalent to:

```
def function(x):
    return function(x) * fun(x)
```

Which is a recursive function without a stop condition. Your initial definition of `function` is shadowed, due to [python's binding rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions,
>   import statements, class and function definitions (these bind the
>   class or function name in the defining block)

You can trace it and verify such behaviour using `python3 -m trace --trace script.py` :

```
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(6):     function = lambda x: function(x) * fun(x)
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(6):     function = lambda x: function(x) * fun(x)

# Repeated until a RecursionError is thrown
```

You can instead bind your function as an argument of the lambda:

```
fun = lambda x: x**2
function = lambda x: x**2
for i in range(2):
    function = lambda x, y=function: y(x) * fun(x)

print(function(2))
```

Which will produce the following trace:

```
--- modulename: script, funcname: <module>
script.py(3): fun = lambda x: x**2
script.py(4): function = lambda x: x**2
script.py(5): for i in range(2):
script.py(6):     function = lambda x, y=function: y(x) * fun(x)
script.py(5): for i in range(2):
script.py(6):     function = lambda x, y=function: y(x) * fun(x)
script.py(5): for i in range(2):
script.py(8): print(function(2))
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(6):     function = lambda x, y=function: y(x) * fun(x)
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(6):     function = lambda x, y=function: y(x) * fun(x)
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(4): function = lambda x: x**2
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(3): fun = lambda x: x**2
--- modulename: script, funcname: <lambda>
script.py(3): fun = lambda x: x**2
64
```

Comment: Oh haha I just wrote this workout myself, crazy timing. Thank you for the explanation though!

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution to this, but did find a workaround. Rather than trying to multiply it straight away, I wrote a function to do the multiplication. This seems to works so I'll just use this instead.

```
def multiplyFun(fun1,fun2):
    fun = lambda x: fun1(x) * fun2(x)
    return fun


fun = lambda x: x**2

function = lambda x: x**2
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    function = multiplyFun(function,fun)

print(function(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate syntax: rather than pass a second argument to the `lambda`, you can use a nested `lambda` where the outer one is evaulated to return the inner one:

```
squared = lambda x: x**2
function = lambda x: x**2

for i in range(2):
    function = (lambda f: lambda x: f(x) * squared(x))(function)

print(function(2))
```

Just seems more generic solution (language-wise) than a defaulted argument.